# need to compute change in time between start time and end time.(Python)

Tags: python

I need to write a program that accepts a start time and end time and computes the change between them in minutes. For example, the start time is 4:30 PM and end time is 9:15 PM then the change in time is 285 min. How do I accomplish this in Python? I only need to compute for a 24 hour period

Comment: Have you attempted anything yourself?

Comment: What if the start time is 4:30 PM and the end time is 9:15 AM?

Comment: Here is my situation. I can accept two strings: "4:30 PM" and "9:15 PM" which are the start and end times. I need to find a way to brake the string apart and compute 60 * hour + minutes for both times and take the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do:

```
from datetime import datetime


def compute_time(start_time, end_time):
    start_datetime = datetime.strptime(start_time, '%I:%M %p')
    end_datetime = datetime.strptime(end_time, '%I:%M %p')
    return (start_datetime - end_datetime).seconds / 60


print compute_time('9:15 PM', '4:30 PM')
```

prints `285`.